# How to detect if the given word is default keyword or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect the given word is default keyword or not in JavaScript?
Example: I have an array like `arr=["function","some"]` these are default keywords. If i write word like as  'function' or 'some' in the editor i need to detect function or some  is a default keyword and return true.

Comment: You have to use a `server-side` technology like node.js, in order to parse text from a file.

Comment: No.I need a example  code for this, friend.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing built-in (not *really*; see below), you just work from the [list of reserved words](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words) in the specification, which are categorized as *keywords* (such as `function`) and *future reserved words* (such as `enum`). But note that new keywords are sometimes added even when they haven't been reserved (`async`, for instance, will be in ES2017 but wasn't previously either a keyword or future reserved word).

One option that comes to mind is to use the `Function` constructor (which creates but doesn't run functions) to see if you can use the word as a variable name:

```js
var results = ["function", "foo", "enum", "class"].map(function(keyword) {
    try {
        new Function("var " + keyword + ";");
        return {keyword: keyword, isReserved: false};
    }
    catch (e) {
        return {keyword: keyword, isReserved: true};
    }
});
console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```